# DDD update collection or update reference

Tags: mapping, domain-driven-design, relationship, updates

I'm still getting my head around ddd, so forgive me if this doesn't make sense.
Let's say I have

```
public class Customer{
    public IList<Order> Orders{get;set;}  // should be encapsulated i know
}

public class Order{
    private Customer _readOnlyCustomer;
    public virtual Customer ReadOnlyCustomer { get { return _readOnlyCustomer; } }
    // possibly
    public virtual void SetCustomer(Customer customer) {_readOnlyCustomer = customer}
}
```

First I am doing the private readonlyCustomer business because my understanding is that one aggregate root should not modify another aggregate root and while I can't enforce this directly do to fluentnhibernate mapping issues, I can at least name it in such a way as to warn that it is not modifiable. I could even make the field readonly in the mapping which would actually enforce this, although that may be a problem given my next question, and I'm not sure how to enforce this on the Customer side, as I could get an order from the customer.orders collection and modify it.  Any thoughts on this issue would be welcomed.  But my real question is.

If I were to create a new order.  Would it make sense to set the customer on the order and save it and have nhibernate update the Customer.Orders Collection or Should I add the order with the customer set to the Customer.Orders collection and then save the Customer.

As I write this I realize, the way I used to do it was to not have the parent referenced in the child and just update the collection on the parent.  This I think has a db call benefit in NH, makes it easier to deal with saving, but makes it harder to traverse.  Now that I am looking at Objects as either Ag Roots or Entities I see that it helps traversal and autonomy of the Ag Roots to have a two way relationship between collection and instance.

Please help me understand which way to use and/or if I'm looking at things correctly.
Thanks,
Raif

Answer (score 0):

> // should be encapsulated i know

Since it can get quite messy to enforce encapsulation, feel free to drop it.
Rely on conventions - be aware what should be modified and where.

> public virtual Customer ReadOnlyCustomer

Is your client talking about read only customers? I bet not.

> If I were to create a new order. Would it make sense to set the customer on the order and save it and have nhibernate update the Customer.Orders Collection or Should I add the order with the customer set to the Customer.Orders collection and then save the Customer.

You don't set customer to orders. You don't add order to the customer.

Customer orders products. This is reflection of how that would look like in code:

```
class customer
  method order(product)
    orders.Add(new Order(product))
```